# Getting SLES RMT Server IP or hostname from client

Tags: repository, suse, sles, patch

We have multiple RMT Servers for patching SLES servers in our environment, how can we check which rmt server is the client currently registered to. Currently we check the baseurl of repo file.
Is there any command or alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the client look in /etc/SUSEConnect